# How to fetch discord.js bot informations like bot username or bot id without login in it and using token

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fetch

All i want is to get simple discord bot informations using token, but i dont want to make bot online.

I tried using discord API and it doesnt work for me but discord.js client it works but makes bot online and i dont want it.

Comment: if you want to get this information, just go to the [Dev Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications). There all those are visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will login to discord, get the bot's info, then logout.

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js'), 
const client = new Client();
client.on('ready', async () => {
console.log(client) // or client.user if you just want client user info
client.destroy() // logs out of Discord
})
client.login('...')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the status of the bot to `invisible` by using [`<client>.setStatus()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setStatus).

Full example:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js'); // Define Discord
const client = new client(); // Define client
client.login('your-token-here'); // Login your Discord bot

client.once('ready', function() { // When the client is ready
    client.setStatus('invisible'); // Makes the bot look offline
});
```

Comment: I dont want to set only offline, i want to make commands doesnt work. I guess a simple method is using discord bot API but idk